# How to use SQL Server stored procedure numeric parameter in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using the following SQL Server stored procedure in one of my C# projects.

```
create procedure [dbo].[TestRecordSelect]
@OMarks numeric(3,1) output
as 
begin
select @OMarks = isnull(sum(cast(OMarks as numeric(3,1))),0) from Marks 
end
```

and I'm getting the desired result i.e. 24.9 when executing the procedure in SQL Server. But when I'm using the same procedure in my C# project and calling the `@OMarks` as follows

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OMarks", SqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
tbomarks.Text = cmd.Parameters["@OMarks"].Value.ToString();
```

I'm getting 25 instead of 24.9 that is the rounded up data.

My problem is I don't want to get 25. I want to get 24.9 in tbomarks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@OMarks", SqlDbType.Decimal);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param.Precision = 3;
param.Scale = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx

Comment: thanks zimdanen now I'm getting the desired result 24.9 in otomarks. thanks again

Answer (score 5):

In your C#, you haven't specified the [Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (or Precision) of your parameter, which means you get zero decimal places.

> Data may be truncated if the Scale property is not explicitly specified and the data on the 
>   server does not fit in scale 0 (the default)
>
> Precision and Scale are required for output parameters

Comment: I agree with you :) That'll teach me to get dinner straight after posting instead of improving my answer ;)